# My application still tries to load an old deleted image from Cloudinary, instead of trying to load the new image

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, cloudinary

My application is trying to load an old image from Cloudinary, instead of the new one uploaded.
The old image is deleted and replaced with the new one in Cloudinary and the public ID of the image is changed in my models.py

But when I run my application, it still tries to load the old image causing this console error:

**GET https://res.cloudinary.com/grezacloud/image/upload/v1/account_default_mly7c9 404 (Not Found)**

I suspect that this issue is not in my code, because the old image was showing fine, and all I did was delete the old image and upload a new image, and change the name in my models.py

In my Account model, I have changed the old image with public-id **"account_default_mly7c9"** to the new uploaded image public-id as seen below:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        # Cloudinary Account image (Default)
        upload_to='images/',
        default='../account_default_lhrxjr' **<----** New changed name
    )
```

Then I `python3 manage.py make migrations`, and then I tried `python3 manage.py migrate` (No changes detected), but when I ran my app the application still tried to load the old image.

*Console Error*
**GET https://res.cloudinary.com/grezacloud/image/upload/v1/account_default_mly7c9 404 (Not Found)**

I have also tried to clear the cache in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see both the public IDs in Cloudinary. These files were destroyed

account_default_mly7c9 destroyed at January 16th 2024, 10:03:03.496 UTC

account_default_lhrxjr destroyed at January 16th 2024, 18:52:50.026 UTC

A New public ID was uploaded at January 16th 2024, 10:03:42.616. (Cannot disclose the public ID due to security reasons).

Can you please check the same and confirm the behavior?

Thanks,

Sree

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).